# cURL not workig as expected on php shell_exec()

Tags: php, linux, shell, curl, request

I'm trying to download a file from an external server, on which I submit a form and returns a download file (PDF).

Copying the request as cURL from the Network tab in Chrome works fine in the Terminal (it downloads the PDF) but not in shell_exec() (I get the submit form page as output).

Here are the verbose output from both curls.

This one belows works fine:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 107.180.12.118...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to operaciones.ahmex.com.mx (107.180.12.118) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
} [5 bytes data]
* (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
} [512 bytes data]
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
{ [102 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
{ [2881 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
{ [333 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
{ [4 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
} [70 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
} [1 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
} [16 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
{ [16 bytes data]
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: OU=Domain Control Validated; CN=operaciones.ahmex.com.mx
*  start date: May 25 17:30:17 2019 GMT
*  expire date: Jul 24 17:04:13 2020 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "operaciones.ahmex.com.mx" matched cert's "operaciones.ahmex.com.mx"
*  issuer: C=US; ST=Arizona; L=Scottsdale; O=GoDaddy.com, Inc.; OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/; CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
} [5 bytes data]
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x55f8419d44c0)
} [5 bytes data]
> POST /potentials/generar_certificado HTTP/2
> Host: operaciones.ahmex.com.mx
> authority: operaciones.ahmex.com.mx
> cache-control: max-age=0
> origin: https://operaciones.ahmex.com.mx
> upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
> content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary1IwLan7m4erUfeoh
> user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.87 Safari/537.36
> sec-fetch-mode: navigate
> sec-fetch-user: ?1
> accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
> sec-fetch-site: same-origin
> referer: https://operaciones.ahmex.com.mx/potentials/
> accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
> accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
> cookie: ci_session=(I removed this)
> Content-Length: 971
> 
{ [5 bytes data]
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS updated)!
} [5 bytes data]
* We are completely uploaded and fine
{ [5 bytes data]

100   971    0     0  100   971      0    701  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--   700
100   971    0     0  100   971      0    407  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:--   406< HTTP/2 200 
< date: Tue, 13 Aug 2019 14:57:41 GMT
< server: Apache
< x-powered-by: PHP/5.6.40
< content-disposition: attachment; filename="CER-0196084.pdf"
< cache-control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< pragma: public
< vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
< content-encoding: gzip
< content-type: application/x-download
< 
{ [5 bytes data]

100 12590    0 11619  100   971   3823    319  0:00:03  0:00:03 --:--:--  4141
100 65749    0 64778  100   971  15423    231  0:00:04  0:00:04 --:--:-- 15650
100 65749    0 64778  100   971  12452    186  0:00:05  0:00:05 --:--:-- 12710
100 65749    0 64778  100   971  10443    156  0:00:06  0:00:06 --:--:-- 13442
100 65749    0 64778  100   971   8990    134  0:00:07  0:00:07 --:--:-- 13439
100 65749    0 64778  100   971   7893    118  0:00:08  0:00:08 --:--:-- 10288
100 78659    0 77688  100   971   8609    107  0:00:09  0:00:09 --:--:--  2675
100  104k    0  103k  100   971  11625    106  0:00:09  0:00:09 --:--:-- 10514
* Connection #0 to host operaciones.ahmex.com.mx left intact
```

This one not:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 107.180.12.118...
* TCP_NODELAY set

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Connected to operaciones.ahmex.com.mx (107.180.12.118) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
} [5 bytes data]
* (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
} [512 bytes data]
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
{ [102 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
{ [2881 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
{ [333 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
{ [4 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
} [70 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
} [1 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
} [16 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
{ [16 bytes data]
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: OU=Domain Control Validated; CN=operaciones.ahmex.com.mx
*  start date: May 25 17:30:17 2019 GMT
*  expire date: Jul 24 17:04:13 2020 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "operaciones.ahmex.com.mx" matched cert's "operaciones.ahmex.com.mx"
*  issuer: C=US; ST=Arizona; L=Scottsdale; O=GoDaddy.com, Inc.; OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/; CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
} [5 bytes data]
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x55a28da8e4c0)
} [5 bytes data]
> POST /potentials/generar_certificado HTTP/2
> Host: operaciones.ahmex.com.mx
> authority: operaciones.ahmex.com.mx
> cache-control: max-age=0
> origin: https://operaciones.ahmex.com.mx
> upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
> content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryWbbB3yby9oTZCuNV
> user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.87 Safari/537.36
> sec-fetch-mode: navigate
> sec-fetch-user: ?1
> accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
> sec-fetch-site: same-origin
> referer: https://operaciones.ahmex.com.mx/potentials/
> accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
> accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
> cookie: ci_session=(I removed this)
> Content-Length: 972
> 
{ [5 bytes data]
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS updated)!
} [5 bytes data]
* We are completely uploaded and fine
{ [5 bytes data]
< HTTP/2 200 
< date: Tue, 13 Aug 2019 15:01:02 GMT
< server: Apache
< x-powered-by: PHP/5.6.40
< vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
< content-encoding: gzip
< content-length: 3120
< content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< 
{ [5 bytes data]

100  4092  100  3120  100   972   3312   1031 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  4343
* Connection #0 to host operaciones.ahmex.com.mx left intact
```

Here's the cURL, just removed the cookie session

```
curl 'https://operaciones.ahmex.com.mx/potentials/generar_certificado' -H 'authority: operaciones.ahmex.com.mx' -H 'cache-control: max-age=0' -H 'origin: https://operaciones.ahmex.com.mx' -H 'upgrade-insecure-requests: 1' -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryWbbB3yby9oTZCuNV' -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.87 Safari/537.36' -H 'sec-fetch-mode: navigate' -H 'sec-fetch-user: ?1' -H 'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3' -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' -H 'referer: https://operaciones.ahmex.com.mx/potentials/' -H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' --data-binary $'------WebKitFormBoundaryWbbB3yby9oTZCuNV\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="nombre2"\r\n\r\nSergio\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryWbbB3yby9oTZCuNV\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="apellido_paterno"\r\n\r\nMendoza\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryWbbB3yby9oTZCuNV\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="apellido_materno"\r\n\r\nNegrete\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryWbbB3yby9oTZCuNV\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="rfc"\r\n\r\nMENS8804144J4\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryWbbB3yby9oTZCuNV\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="importe"\r\n\r\n1500000\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryWbbB3yby9oTZCuNV\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="banco"\r\n\r\nSantander\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryWbbB3yby9oTZCuNV\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="estado"\r\n\r\nJalisco\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryWbbB3yby9oTZCuNV\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="municipio"\r\n\r\nZapopan\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryWbbB3yby9oTZCuNV\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="action"\r\n\r\nEnviar\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryWbbB3yby9oTZCuNV--\r\n' --compressed -o cert.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using php why not try [readfile](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) method?

If you want to use console wget is better for download instead cURL